# Retreiving all active live streams of my subscribed channels through the YouTube API

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API V3 with OAuth and the following scopes: `userinfo.email`, `userinfo.profile`, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube

My goal is to retrieve a list of all the ongoing live streams (e.g. YouTube Gaming) of all the channels I'm subscribed to.

I know that I can use a query like https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=live&maxResults=50&videoCategoryId=20&type=video to get current live streams in the gaming category, but I cannot limit it to my own subscribers, at least not directly.

Then I tried https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&mine=true&maxResults=50, but it seems like I cannot limit the event type to live events.

Then I thought about using the subscription API to get all my subscribers and run all of them through the `/search` and limit it to live events and the category I want, but it seems like the search request does not accept comma-separated list of the YouTube subscription IDs like `/subscription` does.

Lastly, if I'm correct `/liveBroadcast` and `/liveStream` requires the authenticated user to be the owner and then retrieve his own live events only?

Is there any solution that I'm missing?

Thanks a lot!